# YII 2.0.3 view does not render. It goes just blank. Shows only 1 when index is called

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I was going through the *Making a Custom Application
with Yii 2* chapter of **Web Application Development
with Yii 2 and PHP** by **Mark Safronov and Jeffrey Winesett**. However, I am stuck pretty bad! 
The view does not render when I try (running the advanced template on localhost wamp server ) ...
http://localhost/furni/frontend/web/index.php?r=customers
The action it is firing is..

```
 class CustomersController extends Controller{ 
      public function actionIndex() {   
         $records = $this->findRecordsByQuery();
         $this->render('index', compact('records'));
         return true; 
      }
      .......
      .......
 }
```

Please take note of my models folder. It's customer, while views/controller folder/namespace is customer**s**, with an **s**. Table is **customer**.
I have my models in *project-folder\frontend\models\customer*
I have the index.php layout in *project-folder\frontend\views\customers*.
Controller is in *project-folder\frontend\controllers*. I have almost nothing in the view file..

```
<?php
   $this->title = 'Index for customers';
?>
<div class="site-index">
Echo Out Loud
</div>
```

It shows 1 in a blank page!! [image: Here is what the view shows..]

If I change the code to this..

```
<?php
   $this->title = 'Index for customers';
?>
<div class="site-index">
Echo Out Loud
</div>
<?php
die();
```

It renders the view, but without including the layouts for header and footer etc. No head tag, no scripts, styles.. nothing. 
[image]

However, site controller index and other pre-built views are rendering okay! No problem with that. What am I missing, while pulling my hair out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your action will display whatever the action returns. In your case, your action returns 'true', so the display is 1 (for true). If you want it to display the view, then you need to return that, so

```
 class CustomersController extends Controller{ 
  public function actionIndex() {   
     $records = $this->findRecordsByQuery();
     return $this->render('index', compact('records'));
     }
  .......
  .......
 }
```

Comment: ..but in the SiteController.php the actionIndex method also returns $this->render('index');

`return $this->render('index');`
Should I assume that the view is returning true?

Comment: Nevermind, I was just being stupid!! Thanks for pointing out that extra `return true;` at the end!! I didn't notice. Dah!